# Java Inheritance and implementing

Tags: java

I need help to figure How to fix my error code.

THE MAIN :

```
  public class OnlineAccount {
      private int balance = 0;
      public int  getBalance() {
        return balance;
      }
      public boolean withdraw(int amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
          balance -= amount;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
      public boolean deposit(int amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
          balance += amount;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
```

This is the qa:
Define a class called `LimitedOnlineAccount` which extends the `OnlineAccount` class used in the previous questions so that after three withdrawals, a deposit must be made before any more withdrawals can be made.

*** im not allowed to use balance***

My answer:

```
public class LimitedOnlineAccount extends OnlineAccount {
    @Override
    public boolean withdraw(int amount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (amount > 0) {
                amount = getBalance() - amount;
                return super.withdraw(amount);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deposit(int amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            amount = getBalance() + amount;
            return super.withdraw(amount);

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The test says it's 7/10 right.

Thanks.

Comment: Share the super class as well.

Comment: *"the test says its 7/10 right"* - What does that even mean?

Comment: It seems there needs to be a class variable such as `int consecutiveWithdrawals` which is incremented during a withdrawal.  But if `consecutiveWithdrawals == 3` then the withdrawal is blocked.  When a depost is made reset `consecutiveWithdrawals` to 0.

Comment: Depending on what is in the superclass, your code may involve calling `super.withdraw` and `super.deposit`.

Comment: Lots of things wrong here - (1) it doesn't seem right to set the amount to `getBalance() - amount` before withdrawing it; (2) you're calling `super.withdraw` from within the `deposit` method, which can't possibly be the right thing to do; (3) you don't actually have a field that keeps track of how many consecutive withdrawals you've made.  But if you want help fixing these things, you'd need to tell us which test cases are failing, and also show the code for the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not repeat functionality of your super class by checking amount twice.

check my answer:

```
public class LimitedOnlineAccount extends OnlineAccount {
    private int consecutiveWithdrawals = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean withdraw(int amount) {
        if (consecutiveWithdrawals >= 3) 
            return false;

        var status = super.withdraw(amount);
        if (status)
            consecutiveWithdrawals++;

        return status; 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean deposit(int amount) {
        var status = super.deposit(amount);
        if (status) 
            consecutiveWithdrawals = 0;

        return status;
    }
}
```